# In GPT, can a partition be partitioned further into partitions?

Tags: partition, gpt, mbr

I heard that GPT makes MBR's distinction between primary partition, logical partition, and extended partition  disappear.

In GPT, can a partition be partitioned further into partitions, in the same way as  an extended partition in MBR? 
If yes, is it still useful sometimes?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they disappeard. You can build any data structure inside a partition, of course include another partion table, but I don't think the kernel will trivally recognise it, or say it's not very useful at most case. Wildly thinking of an thing you are able to do then think about how can you build something on it is just meaningless. Maybe you want that partition to mimic a whole disk for VM or other hosts using nbd, maybe?

Comment: MBR has these trash because they don't know someday people would want more than four partitions in the old time, then lots of people start to want that, so every OS begin to provide linked-list style MBR table  direct support.

Answer (score 2):

In GPT, a partition cannot be subdivided by partitioning, as MBR required when you had a cap of four first-level partitions on a drive. There's no need, as you can have many more partitions on one drive.